# Flutter display Listview when button pressed

Tags: flutter

```
   List<ServicesMensCollection> menServicesList = []
    ..add(ServicesMensCollection('ihdgfstfyergjergdshf', 'janik', 10))
    ..add(ServicesMensCollection('ihdgfstfyergjerg', 'janik', 10))
    ..add(ServicesMensCollection('ihdgfstfyergjerg', 'janik', 10))
    ..add(ServicesMensCollection('ihdgfstfyergjergdf', 'janik', 10))
  bool _value2 = false;
  void _value2Changed(bool value) => setState(() => _value2 = value);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: new Scaffold(
          body: new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: const Color(0xFFEAEAEA)),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  servicesCategory(),
                  ],),),)); }
Widget servicesButton() {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {listView();},
            child: Text('Mens'),),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {listView();},
            child: Text('Womens')),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {listView();},
            child: Text('Childrens'),
          )]); }

Widget listView(){
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: menServicesList.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return list(index); },);
}

  Widget list(int index){
    return Container(
     child: Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
       children: <Widget>[
        Text(menServicesList[index].name),
        Text(menServicesList[index].name),
        Checkbox(onChanged:_value2Changed,
         value: _value2,
        )],),);
  }}
```

I am implementing listview with checkbox in my project.I have 3 buttons which is created in a row.I want to display the list when the button is clicked.Here the issue is listview is not at all visible for me.I had implemented the same example in android but i don't know how to do this in flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This is a sample screen which you can refer for your implementation.
In this there are 3 sample list which are being replaced to main list on selection, you can add a function which will sort the list based on selection (so no need to have multiple lists)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/*
These are the sample list for demo
 */
List<ItemVO> mainList = List();
List<ItemVO> sampleMenList = [
  ItemVO("1", "Mens 1"),
  ItemVO("2", "Mens 2"),
  ItemVO("3", "Mens 3")
];
List<ItemVO> sampleWomenList = [
  ItemVO("1", "Women 1"),
  ItemVO("2", "Women 2"),
  ItemVO("3", "Women 3")
];
List<ItemVO> sampleKidsList = [
  ItemVO("1", "kids 1"),
  ItemVO("2", "kids 2"),
  ItemVO("3", "kids 3")
];

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _TestScreen();
  }
}

class _TestScreen extends State<TestScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mainList.addAll(sampleMenList);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
              return getCard(index);
            },
            itemCount: mainList.length,
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    mainList.clear();
                    setState(() {
                      mainList.addAll(sampleMenList);
                    });
                  },
                  heroTag: "btn1",
                  child: Text("Mens"),
                ),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    mainList.clear();
                    setState(() {
                      mainList.addAll(sampleWomenList);
                    });
                  },
                  heroTag: "btn2",
                  child: Text("Women"),
                ),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    mainList.clear();
                    setState(() {
                      mainList.addAll(sampleKidsList);
                    });
                  },
                  heroTag: "btn3",
                  child: Text("Kids"),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  /*
    Get the card item for a list
   */
  getCard(int position) {
    ItemVO model = mainList[position];
    return Card(
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "ID:: "+model._id,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5,right: 5)),
            Text(
              "Name:: "+model._name,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    );
  }
}

/*
Custom model
i.e. for itemList
 */
class ItemVO {
  String _id, _name;

  String get id => _id;

  set id(String value) {
    _id = value;
  }

  get name => _name;

  set name(value) {
    _name = value;
  }

  ItemVO(this._id, this._name);
}
```

In your code you didn't added ListView in widget, so it will not show any list, so try adding ListView in widget and then change the list data and try it.

Comment: I tried your solution its not working for me still the page is blank

Comment: have you tried this complete code ? is there any specific error ?

Comment: i tried your sample code.i am not getting error the page is blank still

Comment: Hi, check the code at https://justpaste.it/2nlrd . just copy complete code in main.dart and run the app, let me know if this works ..

Comment: Thank you so much its working but i want list with checkbox.i want to select the item in a list

Comment: for that just add checkbox in Card

Comment: If i change Card into checkbox i am getting error in child:Container field

Answer (score 0):

I think You have 2 choices on how to tackle your problem.

1. Preload the listViews and set their [visibility](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) to gone / invisible
2. Try to play around with the code from this [blog](https://medium.com/@DakshHub/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb)

Comment: k i will try this