# Flutter bring up a list when a button is pressed, and close said list after an option is selected

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building an application for a building that can navigate a user, one of the ways I am doing this is by using a floor plan of the building and I want to draw a path between nodes in this floor plan to create a route. The user enters where they want to be and then route finding algorithm outputs a path, the way I want to build this path is by having a user select a source node and a target node from two seperate lists, I want them to press a button on the map view screen and have a list with these nodes appear but no matter what I try the list will not display.

I've tried using `setState` and having a `ListView` returned but that seems to be where it's failing as such as I have print statements to help verify where in the code I've reached, I don't know if it's the search terms I'm using but nothing I have found so far seems to be related to this kind of use case. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862781/flutter-display-listview-when-button-pressed) is similar to what I want but this is just a list already being displayed and then being updated.

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //currently inside of a scaffold
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
            child: new Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.trip_origin),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _sourceList();
                });
               },
             ),
           ],
          )),
    //extra code as part of scaffold
  }

  Widget _sourceList() {
    print("working1"); //this prints
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          print("working2"); //this does not
          return _buildRow();
        });
  }

  Widget _buildRow() {
    return new ListTile(title: Text(a.name));
  }
```

So basically I just want a list to display when the user presses a button, then have that list disappear after a selection is made. The actual result is I can press the button and nothing is displayed, I only reach working1 in the code not working2.

Comment: you can try using this package:  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/direct_select

Comment: @diegoveloper that looks more like it pertains only to dropdown menus, I just want to display the list after any sort of button is pressed

Comment: Why dont your button just set a boolean state? In build() you can decide which if you want to show list

Comment: @user1462442 oh man that has worked perfectly thank you, I can't believe I didn't think of something like that haha

Comment: @M.Powell Flutter encourages easy answers overall. Choose the least awkward solution.